# Whence is the idea that the deceased is a meilitz yosher?

Tags: sources-mekorot, death

At funerals I have often heard it said that the deceased should be a meilitz yosher (literally one who relates rectitude, meaning someone to advocate on one's behalf in the heavenly courts). Where does this idea come from?

Answer (score 6):

[Gesher HaChaim Volume 2 25:9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31172&st=&pgnum=201&hilite=) brings this down in the name of the [Zohar Parshas Acharei](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14354&st=&pgnum=139).

Comment: If I understand the source correctly, it speaks about a Tzaddik. I heard in a shiur from Rav Reuven Leuchter that a non-tzaddik will be being judged at the time of the burial and unable to be a meilitz yosher for anyone else. So at the levaya it might not be such an appropriate thing to say.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok: Yes you are correct. However this is the source of the idea. As to whether this is applicable to all, I am sure as you indicated that there are those who say not.